# Is there a way to expand resources on prev and next click events on Fullcalendar v5 resourceTimeline view?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar scheduler v.5.3.2, and the *resourcesInitiallyExpanded : true* property when creating de calendar. When I click on prev or next buttons, the calendar renders with previously collapsed resources.

Is there a way to expand all resources without creating the calendar again?
I can't expand resources programmaticaly due to javascript processing problems when loading many resources.

Comment: No I don't believe there is a built-in way to do it. Maybe you can make a feature request - 
 https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: But... `When I click on prev or next buttons, the calendar renders with previously collapsed resources.` ...why is this a problem? If the user collapsed them during their usage, surely they should stay that way? If you keep automatically expanding things they've hidden, that is likely to annoy them. Just because they've changed the date doesn't necessarily mean they suddenly want to see all the resources again - in fact, the opposite is more likely to be true IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need the resources to expand for other purposes. One of them is to manage hidden events on resource hierarchy rows.